# iOS 12: Is there a URL to open the Settings app's language screen?

Tags: ios, internationalization, settings

For Khan Academy's iOS app, we want to offer a screen that'll help our learners switch what language the app uses.

Starting in iOS 13, we'll be able to send our users to our app's screen in the Settings app, with the following:

```
let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)
```

...however, on iOS 12 and earlier, our users would need to go to the Settings app's "General > Language and Region" screen. **Is there a URL available that'll open that part of Settings?**

Comment: No, all other preferences uris are considered private api